# Obtaining METEOR scores for Japanese text

Tags: nltk, nltk-book

I wish to produce METEOR scores for several Japanese strings. I have imported `nltk`, `wordnet` and `omw` but the results do not convince me it is working correctly.

```py
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from nltk.translate.meteor_score import single_meteor_score

nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('omw')

reference = "チップは含まれていません。"
hypothesis = "チップは含まれていません。"

print(single_meteor_score(reference, hypothesis))
```

This outputs `0.5` but surely it should be much closer to `1.0` given the reference and hypothesis are identical?

Do I somehow need to specify which wordnet language I want to use in the call to `single_meteor_score()` for example:

`single_meteor_score(reference, hypothesis, wordnet=wordnetJapanese`.

Comment: It raises this error: `TypeError: "hypothesis" expects pre-tokenized hypothesis (Iterable[str])`

Answer (score 0):

Pending review by a qualified linguist, I appear to have found a solution. I found an open source tokenizer for Japanese. I pre-processed all of my reference and hypothesis strings to insert spaces between Japanese tokens and then run the `nltk.single_meteor_score()` over the files.